# Keyed Particle System with Force Fields

Tags: particles, transforms, force-fields

I have one object that needs to explode into cubes and then form a second object. I saw that one way of doing that is by using keyed physics type, but it looks to boring and static.

I need the transition to be more random and it needs to look like an explosion in the beginning. Is there a way to use a force field and a turbulence field with the keyed particle system?

Thanks!